# Flutter: How to parse json nested map on dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Here is the json file that i want to parse:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Weekly Adjusted Prices and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-03-25",
        "4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Weekly Adjusted Time Series": {
        "2020-03-25": {
            "1. open": "137.0100",
            "2. high": "154.3300",
            "3. low": "132.5200",
            "4. close": "146.9200",
            "5. adjusted close": "146.9200",
            "6. volume": "235583286",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000"
        },
        "2020-03-20": {
            "1. open": "140.0000",
            "2. high": "150.1500",
            "3. low": "135.0000",
            "4. close": "137.3500",
            "5. adjusted close": "137.3500",
            "6. volume": "421347734",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000"
        },
}
```

I just wanted to get the date, open, and close. I tried finding stuff online but still was unable to do so.

Here is my TimeSeries class:

```
class TimeSeries {
  final String date;
  final double open;
  final double close;

  TimeSeries({this.date, this.open, this.close});

  factory TimeSeries.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TimeSeries(
      date: json[''],
      open: double.parse(json['1. open']),
      close: double.parse(json['4. close']),
    );
  }
}
```

And these are my function for now:

```
Future getTimeSeries(String stock) async {
    print("Starting get request");
    http.get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo").then((res){
      print("received response.");
      var resObj = json.decode(res.body);
     }).catchError((e) {
      print("Failed to get response.");
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
class TimeSeries {
  final String date;
  final double open;
  final double close;

  TimeSeries({this.date, this.open, this.close});

  factory TimeSeries.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, String indexDate) {
    return TimeSeries(
      date: indexDate,
      open: double.parse(json["Weekly Adjusted Time Series"][indexDate]['1. open']),
      close: double.parse(json["Weekly Adjusted Time Series"][indexDate]['4. close']),
    );
  }
}
```

And you can call the constructor as follows

```
List<TimeSeries> datesList(json) {
   List<TimeSeries> dates;
   for (date in json["Weekly Adjusted Time Series"]) {
       dates.add(TimeSeries.fromJson(json, date));
    }
    return dates;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to do some mapping here. Your `TimeSeries` class is enough, but you need to tweak your `getTimeSeries` function. Firstly, you may want to change its return type to return a `Future` with a `List<TimeSeries>`, because you'll be getting a list of those.

Inside the `then` callback of your HTTP call you want to firstly get inside the JSON map you have data in, so in that case it's `resObj['Weekly Adjusted Time Series']`. Then, run `map` on this and here is the place where you want to instantiate `TimeSeries` (I also used `final` instead of `var` - it's just a good practise to use it where you don't need `var`):

```dart
final resObj = json.decode(res.body);

return resObj.map((date, fields) {
  return TimeSeries(DateTime.parse(date), fields['1. open'], fields['4. close']);
});
```

IMO `TimeSeries.fromJson` won't help here, because you don't get the `date` field from this inside map in your JSON.

Your whole new code would look like this:

```dart
class TimeSeries {
  final String date;
  final double open;
  final double close;

  TimeSeries({this.date, this.open, this.close});
}

Future<List<TimeSeries>> getTimeSeries(String stock) async {
  print("Starting get request");

  return http.get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo").then((res){
    print("received response.");
    final resObj = json.decode(res.body);

    return resObj.map((date, fields) {
      return TimeSeries(date, fields['1. open'], fields['4. close']);
    });
   }).catchError((e) {
    print("Failed to get response.");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use this library https://github.com/k-paxian/dart-json-mapper

Of course if you don't like to hardcode `.fromJson` methods for all your model classes manually and having fun with debugging & supporting them later.